# Proving the most efficient profile for gear teeth is an epicycloid

Tags: variational-calculus

I'm reading 'Revolution in time' by David S. Landes.

It says that the most efficient (i.e. with least friction) profile for meshing gear teeth (for the old watches which used balance spring and wheel teeth) is an epicycloid. It also says that Philippe de La Hire and Olaf Roemer (astronomer) proved that.

I tried find the related source, but I failed. The book has its references, but the book itself is very old, and the sources are way older, so I couldn't find appropriate article online.

And I cannot prove it myself. Well, it seems somewhat obvious, but I think it's hindsight, and I cannot express it in mathematical form. 
Does anybody have an idea?